# Applying bookkeeping format to range via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to apply a bookkeeping format to my range via VBA.

I made the adaptions regarding double quotes (`""`).

An excerpt from my code:

```vb
..
.ListColumns(1).name = "Datum"
.ListColumns("Datum").Range.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
.ListColumns(2).name = "Saldo"
.ListColumns("Saldo").Range.NumberFormat = "_ CHF * #’##0.00_ ;_ CHF * -#’##0.00_ ;_ CHF * ""-""??_ ;_ @_ "
..
```

This code yields

> Unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class

with a marker pointing to the bottom line.

It works for the `"Datum"` column though.

The numberformat is valid because I copied it from the custom format list and it works when applied via GUI.

Comment: The numberformat is valid because I copied it right from the custom format list and it works when applied via GUI

Answer (score 1):

I tried to replicate and i believe it's not accepting it due to the "CHF"

I've tried this many different ways and seems to work consistently:

```
    Selection.NumberFormat = _
    "_ ""CHF"" * #’##0.00_ ;_ ""CHF"" * -#’##0.00_ ;_ ""CHF"" * """"-""""??_ ;_ @_ "
```

You can replace the "Selection" with whatever range you're using.

Example of the output i got, is this what you want it to look like?

[image]

Comment: Thank you that does the trick. So basically you just wrapped the CHF into double doublequotes?

Comment: On second thought: The apostroph should not be placed in front of numbers, it serves as a delimiter for 1000 s It doesn't do that when I apply the original format via GUI

Comment: So I've done some experimentation, it looks like excel only understands decimals and commas as thousands delimiters... I'll take a look into if that's a setting we can change. In the meantime, I tested using the macro to build the exact same format with both commas and apostrophes - its works fine with commas.

Comment: Okay, I have found a solution. 1) goto [File] > [Options] > [Advanced] > [✓] uncheck "Use system separator" then change the thousands separator to an apostrophe. 2) Use 
     Selection.NumberFormat = _
    "_ ""CHF"" * #,##0.00_ ;_ ""CHF"" * -#,##0.00_ ;_ ""CHF"" * """"-""""??_ ;_ @_ "
    And excel will automatically make them apostrophes.